# How to get Java sockets work with public IP on google cloud

Tags: java, sockets, networking, server

I'm planning to create a server and run it on google cloud VM, this code is working fine in the localhost but it won't run on External IP.

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Server extends Thread {
    private ServerSocket serverSocket;

    public Server(int port) throws IOException {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
    }

    public void run() {
        while(true) {
            try {
                System.out.println("Waiting for Connection ");
                Socket server = serverSocket.accept();

                System.out.println("Just connected to " + server.getRemoteSocketAddress());
                DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(server.getInputStream());

                System.out.println(in.readUTF());
                DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(server.getOutputStream());
                out.writeUTF("Goodbye");
                server.close();

            } catch (SocketTimeoutException s) {
                System.out.println("Socket timed out!");
                break;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String [] args) throws UnknownHostException {
        int port = 4999;
        try {
            Thread t = new Server(port);
            t.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

and this is for the client

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Client {

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        String serverName = "localhost";
        int port = Integer.parseInt("4999");
        try {
            System.out.println("Connecting to " + serverName + " on port " + port);
            Socket client = new Socket(serverName, port);
            OutputStream outToServer = client.getOutputStream();
            DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(outToServer);

            out.writeUTF("[Client]Hello from " + client.getLocalSocketAddress());
            InputStream inFromServer = client.getInputStream();
            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(inFromServer);

            System.out.println("[Server] " + in.readUTF());
            client.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

and this is the net config of the google VM instance:
Internal ip-> 10.138.0.13 (nic0) | External ip-> 34.83.94.126

can you please tell me how to get it running on a public ip.

Comment: What does "it won't run (on Google cloud VM)" mean?  Do you get one or more error messages?  Is there a Java interpreter on the Google cloud?

Comment: the problem is i can't find the server by the public ip and i could not find the port forwarding option on Google Cloud, yes the VM runs debian 10 and no error just the error on the client side, it can't find the server!

Comment: So you can't connect to the servers IP address? How do you upload code to the server? Where did you find the  IP address 34.83.94.126?